# Type inference against type defined in unreferenced namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, type-inference

Given a class and namespace defined as follows;

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Foo
    { 
    }
}
```

And the following...

```
namespace Factories
{
    using Models;

    class FooFactory
    {
        public Foo GetFoo()
        {
            return new Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally...

```
namespace InferenceTest
{
    using Factories;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Foo foo = new FooFactory().GetFoo();
        }
    }
}
```

As you would expect, this code fails to compile with the error **"The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

However, if I change the line to this...

```
var foo = new FooFactory().GetFoo();
```

Then it compiles and runs just fine.

Why is there this difference? What is it about type inference that allows it to see types in namespaces that have not been imported. Are namespaces just syntactic sugar?

Comment: I don't know this well enough to post an authoritative answer however I would say when you use `var` you are leaving it up to the compiler to determine the type, so having a qualified namespace would be of no assistance, as it knows what the type is. When you use an explicit type, you may be referring to a different type with the same name (different namespace) so you must be explicit in how to qualify the type.

Comment: You don't have to have a using directive to declare a variable of that type, it just allows you to use a shortened type declaration. `Models.Foo foo = new FooFactory().GetFoo();` would compile just fine. With var it doesn't matter what using directive you have because you are not saying "declare variable foo of this specific type" you are saing "declare varable foo and infer the type from the initialisation".

Comment: Oh OK, so the "var" is really just being replaced by the full qualified type name.. "Models.Foo" ?

Comment: I am not a compiler expert but my intuation says it is not being replaced by anything, a type declaration tells the compiler what type the variable is, var just tells the compiler to infer the type.

Comment: Fair enough - makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `var foo = new FooFactory().GetFoo();` compile is simple. The compiler infer that foo is Models.Foo type not only Foo.
Is symilar to push `Models.Foo foo2 = new FooFactory().GetFoo();`.
Notice that `Foo foo2 = new FooFactory().GetFoo();` is diferent.

Answer (score 1):

`namespaces that have not been imported` is your invalid reason; you don't import namespaces but use them as if they were local. The only import that happening in compiling is referencing an assembly even though it isn't real import, just some metadata is imported. (Such as versions and GUIDs)

It means that when you reference assembly such as `System.dll` you can use all of the classes in it; to show you the extent of the meaning of it I will give you this reflection example:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main( ) {
        System.Type.GetType("System.Console")
            .GetMethod("WriteLine",new[] {System.Type.GetType("System.String")})
            .Invoke(null,new object[]{"Hello World"});
    }
}
```

You didn't "imported" any namespace but still used `string` `Console`'s `WriteLine` and some reflection features without the compiler knowing it in compile time because you had `System.dll` referenced to your project.